# How to make QLabel behave like a link without html?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm working on my app and I need QLabel be divided into 2 strings but the way it saves it`s hyberlink behavior.

I know how to create hyperlink using QLabel:

```
link = QLabel('''<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Some text</a>''')
```

But how can I display the same QLabel but with the text like:

```
text = 'some /n text'
```

Because if you use:

```
link = QLabel('''<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">{0}</a>'''.format(text))
```

it doesn`t work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you using html then the line break you have to do with `<br>`:

```py
text = 'some <br> text'
link = QLabel()
link.setText('''<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">{0}</a>'''.format(text))
```